# Upload multiple files using php function

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a single file upload in my functions.php file which works well.I would like to change it to upload multiple files, I have seen some video and [sites](https://makitweb.com/multiple-files-upload-at-once-with-php/) that show a simple way but I'm not sure how to change my code to be similar to what I see on the web. This is my single file upload code below:

```
add_filter( 'submit_job_form_fields', 'frontend_add_image_field' );
function frontend_add_image_field( $fields ) {
  $fields['job']['job_image'] = array(
   'label'       => __( 'Upload Image', 'job_manager' ),
   'type'        => 'file',
   'required'    => true,
   'placeholder' => '',
   'priority'    => 9
   );
   return $fields;
  }'
```

This is what I see on the web:

```
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>

</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 // Count total files
$countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
 
 // Looping all files
for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
   
   // Upload file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename);
    
 }
} 
?>
```

HOW DO I USE THAT CODE IN MY functions.php file, I am still new to PHP, please assist.

Comment: Both approaches have nothing to do with each other. Your current attempt relies on some framework to do the work for you. The code snippet you pasted "from the web" shows the standard way in php. You need to decide wht you want to do: raw solution you need to code (and test and maintain and secure!) on your own or a framework, in which case you need to look into that framework.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, how can I tweak my code to upload multiple files, doesn't necessarily have to be similar to what is on the other web code. I'm not sure how to use the multiple attribute on my code.

Comment: As said: your corrent code relies on some framework. We do not know that framework, you did not mention it, so there is nothing we can help here.